# Making a javascript function that returns itself where it is an instance of itself

Tags: javascript, instanceof, single-instance

In Javascript, is it at all possible to make function `Foo()` such that *both* `(Foo() == Foo)`, and `(Foo() instanceof Foo)`?

This almost works:

```
function Foo() { Object.setPrototypeOf(Foo,this); return Foo; }
```

so `new Foo() instanceof Foo` in this case, but if I just call `Foo` without `new`, it doesn't work.

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: `Object.setPrototypeOf(Foo,this);` sets *Foo*'s  prototype to an instance of *Foo*, which still has the original *Foo* prototype as its `[[Prototype]]` (because it was constructed before you swapped the prototype). Subsequent calls will keep inserting new objects on the prototype chain. Messy. Call it without *new* and things really go to pot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to do

```
function Foo() { return Foo; }             // Foo() === Foo
Object.setPrototypeOf(Foo, Foo.prototype); // Foo instanceof Foo
```

Remember that `a instanceof B` is equivalent to `B.prototype.isPrototypeOf(a)`

Comment: And of course, please never use this anywhere for real…

Comment: @RobG [`isProtototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf) also searches the chain

Comment: Hmm, one day I'll work out how to read the spec, or it will be written in a way that is reasonably understandable…